# setting the 'hidden' attribute on a partion from Linux (parted) isnt respected by Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, gpt, diskpart, parted

when I set the 'hidden' flag on a GPT partition it's not respected by Windows 8.1 (Windows attempts to mound, throws UI, etc).  However if I set the 'hidden' flag from diskpart.exe it is respected - are these two 'hiddens' different?

how can I set the bit from Linux such that it's respected from Windows?

```
GNU Parted 3.0
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
print
Model: LaCie P9220 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name         Flags
 1      1049kB  8001MB  8000MB  fat32        SD_Recovery
 2      8001MB  8101MB  101MB   ext4         SD_OS        hidden
 3      8101MB  8201MB  99.6MB               SD_Page      hidden
 4      8201MB  520GB   512GB   ext4         SD_Data0     hidden
 5      520GB   1000GB  480GB   ext4         SD_Data1     hidden
```

and the same disk from Windows

```
DISKPART> lis vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  ...
  Volume 7     E                FAT32  Partition   7629 MB  Healthy
  Volume 8     H                RAW    Partition     96 MB  Healthy
  Volume 9     I                RAW    Partition     95 MB  Healthy
  Volume 10    J                RAW    Partition    476 GB  Healthy
  Volume 11    K                RAW    Partition    447 GB  Healthy

DISKPART>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure which attribute bits parted uses to define a hidden partition, you would need to look at the source code. But from what you have experienced it must be different.

Microsoft defines these partition attributes for GPT:
Bit 60 - Read Only,
Bit 62 - Hidden,
Bit 63 - Do not automount

For more information see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries).

And how would you do this from Linux? Well you could check the parted documentation to see if allows you to set custom attribute bits for a partition entry; and if not then you would need to modify the source code to have it set the bit microsoft uses as well.

Comment: try `gdisk` (gpt version of `fdisk`).  `x` (for expert) -> `a` (for attribute).  The prompt there has those same values (62 hidden, 63 do not automount, etc.)  parted might not be applying its flags properly to GPT partitions.  (when it works, it's nice, but parted isn't always the most up-to-date piece of software, unfortunately.  @stuck may have stumbled into a not-GPT-aware corner of parted.)

Answer (score 0):

Parted and gdisk differ in how they call the different GPT partition attribute bits:

| bit | parted | gdisk | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | hidden | system partition | defined in UEFI specification as "Required Partition" |
| 1 | - | hide from EFI | defined in UEFI specification as " No Block IO Protocol " |
| 2 | legacy_boot | legacy BIOS bootable | defined in UEFI specification as "Legacy BIOS Bootable" |
| 60 | - | read-only | [defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753455(v=ws.11)) |
| 61 | - | - | [defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753455(v=ws.11)) as "shadow copy of another partition" |
| 62 | - | hidden | [defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753455(v=ws.11)) |
| 63 | no_automount | do not automount | [defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753455(v=ws.11)) |

Other "flags" in parted relate to specific partition type GUIDs

| GUID | parted | gdisk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B | boot, esp | EF00, EFI system partition |
| C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B | - | 8300, Linux filesystem |
| 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F | swap | 8200, Linux swap |
| EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 | msftdata | 0700, Microsoft basic data |